# preg_replace of php code

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I am writing an application that will look at a single record, obtain values from about 12 flags (0 or 1), look up those flags against a status table (in MySQL) and return a variable called `$status_message` which is in that table.

In this table I need to have hyperlinks (working fine) but also echo some variables, i.e.

```
You have no bids for {{$row->_item_name}}
```

or

```
View this item now <a href="item?{{$row->itemid}}"> by clicking here</a>
```

Now I need item name and the other example to be translated into `<?php echo $row->_item_name; ?>`

I have tried a `preg_replace` with the following:

```
<?php
 $find = array('/{{/', '/}}/');
 $replace = array('<?php echo ', ' ?>');
 echo preg_replace($find, $replace, $status_message);
?>
```

but this is not working.

Can anyone advise how I can get the desired result and 'echo' the variable in the MySQL field?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Had a brainwave. Much simpler,

instead of `$row->_item_name` I just put `{{itemname}}` in the string. I then use the following code:

```
<?php

 $message_buyer = str_replace('{{itemname}}', $row->_item_name , $message_buyer);
 echo $message_buyer;

?>
```

so no need to have `<?php` calls in the string at all.

Comment: ok too quick to celebrate.. when i have a replacement that is a link, whether i use preg_place or str_replace the link generates OK (checking source), but wraps itself in quotes i.e  "my link" when rendering which stops it appearing

Comment: what do you mean by it stops it from appearing?

Comment: Looks like str_replace is messing up the special characters in my <a href="" etc> ie to render " i have to put \" ... is there a way of making my str_replace detect these special characters and automatically put the \ in place?